# Use "than" or "then" in this sentence as response?

Tags: word-usage

Is it "play better than" or "play better then" as response to "we can't lose this"?
Now I am writing stuff to meet the quality standards of posts.

Comment: Is anyone going to answer this than? I think it shows no evidence of prior research.

Comment: I thought "then" would only be used in context with time. So is your "than" correct or was it a joke?

Comment: It was a joke. I'm sorry if it was a bit dismissive / demeaning. The usage difference is that you *play better **than** someone who can't play as well as you*. But if there's someone else who can play better than you, ***then*** he will probably beat you.

Comment: Welcome to ELL, sotix. We expect people to do a little research before asking questions. In this case, you could look up **then** in a good dictionary, for example http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/then. Take a look at the final section **then (adverb) RESULT** and see whether it answers your question. If not, add the details of your research to your question (and provide links if possible) and explain what you don't understand. Merry Christmas!

Comment: sorry all and thanks for the help. I will do better research next time :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would use "Play better, **then**" in this case. You're implying the rest of the sentence - in full it would be "**If** we can't lose this, **then** [you should] play better".

"Play better **than**" would not make sense in this context.

Comment: ok thanks. i thought "then" would only be used in context with time and was confused because someone suggested otherwise

Comment: Yes, **then** is generally used in context with time, but it can also be used to define a condition. Look up If...Then... logic.

Answer (score 2):

As a standalone answer "*play better then*" is the right option.

You use "than" when you compare between different things. That means when using "*than*", you have to name the other object. So in your case it might be

> We can't lose this! - Play better than our opponent!

or even using both "*then*" and "*than*":

> We can't lose this! - Then play better than our opponent!